# Using reactiveValues across multiple modules in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to use reactiveValues across multiple modules in an R shiny app.

I have set up an example to illustrate my problem. It consists of a main application containing a reactiveValue which is a data frame of 3 columns and 3 modules designed to "read", "write" and "read and write" the reactiveValue.

- Read: Application -> Module
- Write: Module -> Application
- Read and Write: Application <-> Module

I get the error:

> Warning: Error in <-: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Note that the code works if the reactiveValue is just a simple variable e.g. integer, but not with a data frame where components need to be updated rather than the whole data frame.

I have found the following link very useful. Not sure if it covers my case.
https://www.ardata.fr/en/post/2019/04/26/share-reactive-among-shiny-modules/

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

readUI <- function(id, label = "Read") {

  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    valueBoxOutput(ns("showX"))
  )
}

read <- function(input, output, session, x) {

  ns <- session$ns

  output$showX <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(x(), "x")
  })

}

writeUI <- function(id, label = "Write") {

  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    selectizeInput(ns("selectX"), "Select a value for x", choices = 1:10),
    actionButton(ns("submit"), "Submit")
  )
}

write <- function(input, output, session) {

  ns <- session$ns

  toReturn <- reactiveValues(x = data.frame(a=c(1), b=c(2), c=c(3)), trigger = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    toReturn$x$a <- as.numeric(input$selectX)
    toReturn$trigger <- toReturn$trigger + 1
  })

  return(toReturn)

}

readAndWriteUI <- function(id, label = "ReadAndWrite") {

  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    valueBoxOutput(ns("showX")),
    selectizeInput(ns("selectX"), "Select a value for x", choices = 1:10),
    actionButton(ns("submit"), "Submit")
  )

}

readAndWrite <- function(input, output, session, x) {

  ns <- session$ns

  toReturn <- reactiveValues(x = x, trigger = NULL)

  output$showX <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(x(), "x")
  })

  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    toReturn$x$a <- as.numeric(input$selectX)
    toReturn$trigger <- toReturn$trigger + 1
  })

  return(toReturn)

}

ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),

  dashboardSidebar(),

  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(id = "mainTabSetPanel",
      tabPanel("Read", readUI("Read")),
      tabPanel("Write", writeUI("Write")),
      tabPanel("ReadAndWrite", readAndWriteUI("ReadAndWrite"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(x = data.frame(a=c(1), b=c(2), c=c(3)))

  callModule(read, "Read", reactive(rv$x))
  output_Write <- callModule(write, "Write")
  output_ReadAndWrite <- callModule(readAndWrite, "ReadAndWrite", reactive(rv$x))

  observeEvent(output_Write$trigger, {
    print("Updating x from Write")
    rv$x <- output_Write$x
    #updateTabsetPanel(session, "mainTabSetPanel", selected = "Read")
  })

  observeEvent(output_ReadAndWrite$trigger, {
    print("Updating x from ReadAndWrite")
    rv$x <- output_ReadAndWrite$x
    #updateTabsetPanel(session, "mainTabSetPanel", selected = "Read")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

readUI <- function(id, label = "Read") {

    ns <- NS(id)

    tagList(
        valueBoxOutput(ns("showX"))
    )
}

read <- function(input, output, session, x) {

    ns <- session$ns

    output$showX <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox(x(), "x")
    })

}

writeUI <- function(id, label = "Write") {

    ns <- NS(id)

    tagList(
        selectizeInput(ns("selectX"), "Select a value for x", choices = 1:10),
        actionButton(ns("submit"), "Submit")
    )
}

write <- function(input, output, session) {

    ns <- session$ns

    toReturn <- reactiveValues(x = data.frame(a=c(1), b=c(2), c=c(3)), trigger = 0)

    observeEvent(input$submit, {
        toReturn$x$a <- as.numeric(input$selectX)
        toReturn$trigger <- toReturn$trigger + 1
    })

    return(toReturn)

}

readAndWriteUI <- function(id, label = "ReadAndWrite") {

    ns <- NS(id)

    tagList(
        valueBoxOutput(ns("showX")),
        selectizeInput(ns("selectX"), "Select a value for x", choices = 1:10),
        actionButton(ns("submit"), "Submit")
    )

}

readAndWrite <- function(input, output, session, x) {

    ns <- session$ns

    toReturn <- reactiveValues(x = x, trigger = 0)

    observeEvent(toReturn, {
        toReturn$x <- toReturn$x()
    }, once = TRUE)

    output$showX <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox(x(), "x")
    })

    observeEvent(input$submit, {
        toReturn$x$a <- as.numeric(input$selectX)
        toReturn$trigger <- toReturn$trigger + 1
    })

    return(toReturn)

}

ui <- dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),

    dashboardSidebar(),

    dashboardBody(
        tabsetPanel(id = "mainTabSetPanel",
                    tabPanel("Read", readUI("Read")),
                    tabPanel("Write", writeUI("Write")),
                    tabPanel("ReadAndWrite", readAndWriteUI("ReadAndWrite"))
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    rv <- reactiveValues(x = data.frame(a=c(1), b=c(2), c=c(3)))

    callModule(read, "Read", reactive(rv$x))
    output_Write <- callModule(write, "Write")
    output_ReadAndWrite <- callModule(readAndWrite, "ReadAndWrite", reactive(rv$x))

    observeEvent(output_Write$trigger, {
        print("Updating x from Write")
        rv$x <- output_Write$x
        #updateTabsetPanel(session, "mainTabSetPanel", selected = "Read")
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

    observeEvent(output_ReadAndWrite$trigger, {
        print("Updating x from ReadAndWrite")
        rv$x <- output_ReadAndWrite$x
        #updateTabsetPanel(session, "mainTabSetPanel", selected = "Read")
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The key is adding in the line `toReturn$x <- toReturn$x()` as you're dealing with `reactives` and `reactiveValues` but this must only run once, hence the below:

```
observeEvent(toReturn, {
    toReturn$x <- toReturn$x()
}, once = TRUE)
```

An independent issue I picked up was your code was only working once even for the `write` module. So, I changed `trigger = NULL` to `trigger = 0` (as you can't add to a `NULL` value) but then had to add in `ignoreInit = TRUE` for the `observeEvents` in the `server` to ignore them on startup.

Feel free to test these by taking out my additions one by one to understand the process. Comment below if anything needs clarifying.

Comment: This is only half an answer. I've created another problem that I'm working on now.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. toReturn$x <- toReturn$x() was the key I was missing.

Comment: Glad to help. It's often useful to put a `browser()` at the point of the error to see what is actually happening (which is what I did).